# Download multiple files and folders from Azure blob storage - node.js

Tags: node.js

I have created a node API method to download a blob file from azure storage and its working fine and I have written the code to download only one file, for multiple files download I am trying to generate zip file in azure Blob Storage is there any method to zip file in azure and downlod the zip

Comment: Can you post your code for downloading the one blob? What have you tried so far regarding the many blob download?

Answer (score 0):

Please look into the sample examples for javascript https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/tree/master/sdk/storage/storage-blob/samples/javascript

Currently, there is no batch API for multiple file downloads and you have to make your own parallel downloads which you can upload back to blob storage after compressing to .zip